# Rational curves in ${\mathbb P}^n$ and immersion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

In the paper of Herbert Clemens

*[Curves on generic hypersurfaces](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1986_4_19_4_629_0.pdf)*

the author shows that for a generic hypersurface $V$ of ${\mathbb P}^n$ of sufficiently high degree there is no rational curve on $V$.

The main theorem is a general statement about immersed genus $g$ curves in $V$, and it seems rather elementary to remove the immersed condition for rational curves, and derive the above statement about rational curves. But what is the argument? Is it because every rational curve in ${\mathbb P}^n$ is a multiple cover of an immersed one (if so why is this true)? Or is it because of the property of $V$?

Comment: There are plenty of rational curves that are not multiple covers of immersed curves.  A cuspidal cubic curve in the projective plane is not an immersion from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: To Jason: then is it because of the property of the hypersurface V?

Comment: What property? Your question is unclear.

Comment: To clarify, Theorem 1.1 in the paper implies that a general hypersurface contains no immersed rational curves once its degree exceeds roughly half the dimension. The OP is asking: why we can remove the immersed assumption (which is remarked right below the theorem)?

Comment: once the degree exceeds twice the dimension of the hyperaurface?

Comment: To DCT: that's correct.

Comment: I do not believe that Clemens claims that there are no nonconstant morphisms from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $V$.  I believe Clemens *defines* "rational curve" to mean an immersion from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $V$.  I found nowhere in his paper where Clemens claims that there are no ramified morphisms from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to $V$.

Comment: To Jason: then how about the later work of Voisin? Does she in that paper also regard rational curves as immersed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP clarified that the question is not merely about what is stated and proved in the article of Clemens; the OP would like to know what has been proved after the article of Clemens.  There is important work by Lawrence Ein, Gianluca Pacienza, Claire Voisin, and Geng Xu.  To the best of my knowledge, the current state of the art is the following theorem of Riedl and Woolf that applies in arbitrary characteristic (not merely characteristic $0$).

Eric Riedl and Matthew Woolf 
Rational curves on complete intersections in positive characteristic 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05958.pdf

**Theorem 1.2.** [Riedl and Woolf]  For every field $K$, for every pair of integers $n,d\geq 1$ with $d\geq 2n-1$, every "very general" degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n_K$ contains no rational curves, i.e., every morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to the hypersurface is constant.

To be precise, in the projective $K$-scheme $\mathbb{P} H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_K,\mathcal{O}(d)) \cong \mathbb{P}^{\binom{n+d}{n}-1}_K$ parameterizing degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$, there exist countably many irreducible, Zariski closed subschemes $Z_i$ of codimension $\geq d-(2n-2)$ such that for every algebraically closed extension $k/K$ and for every $k$-point of $\mathbb{P} H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_K,\mathcal{O}(d))$ that is contained in no $Z_i$, every $k$-morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ to the associated hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is constant.